# Teradata wildcard in join definition

Tags: sql, teradata

I have joined tables like bellow:

```
select a.*, b.col4, b.col5 from table a
inner join table b
on  a.col2=b.col2
and a.col3=b.col3
```

It can happen that in b.col2, b.col3 can be value '*', which should be something like wildcard, meaninng, that in this case we can join value of b.col2  on any value of a.col2 or value b.col3 on any value a.col3.

Would you please help me define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a default.  One method is multiple comparison:

```
select a.*,
       coalesce(b.col4, bdef3.col4, bdef2.col4, bdef.col4) as col4, b.col5
       coalesce(b.col5, bdef3.col5, bdef2.col5, bdef.col5) as col5
from tablea a left join
     tableb b
     on b.col2 = a.col2 and b.col3 = a.col3 left join
     tableb bdef3
     on b.col2 = a.col2 and b.col3 = '*' left join
     tableb bdef2
     on b.col2 = '*' and b.col3 = a.col3 left join
     tableb bdef
     on b.col2 = '*' and b.col3 = '*';
```

You may want a `where` clause if you want to guarantee some match:

```
where (b.col2 is not null or bdef3.col2 is not null or bdef2.col2 is not null or bdef.col2 is not null)
```

I think the above is more efficient, but you can express this more succinctly as:

```
select a.*, b.col4, b.col5
from tablea a left join
     tableb b
     on (b.col2 = a.col2 or b.col2 = '*') and
        (b.col3 = a.col3 or b.col3 = '*')
qualify 1 = row_number() over (partition by a.id order by (case when b.col2 = '*' then 2 else 1 end), (case when b.col3 = '*' then 2, else 1 end))
```